# Google Apps Script in Spreadsheet storing decimal values instead of Integer in Project Properties

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first post.  I tried searching via Google and this site but really couldn't find any info about typecasting or converting numerical values within GAS specifically in this scenario.  So here the problem:

I have a very basic script attached to a Google Spreadsheet.  The script simply keeps track of the last row that was populated, increments the value by one, so that the next row can be populated.  I'm storing the "last row used" as a Project Property.  For some reason, the script keeps writing the value back into Project Properties as a decimal value, which throws off the whole script since it seems I can't use a decimal value to reference a cell location.

Here is the code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D13").getValue().toString();
  var last = ScriptProperties.getProperty("last");

  var therowx = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty("therow"));
  Browser.msgBox("The last row is: " + therowx);

  if( value != last ) {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("last", value);
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("therow", therowx + 1);
  }
}
```

Assuming that I've pre-set the Property to 1 before running the script, once this method fires, it sets it to 2.0 instead of just 2.  I've tried wrapping the method call with the Number() and parseInt() functions but they don't seem to make a difference.

I'm open to suggestions, as I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but just not quite sure what.

Comment: According to the docs, getProperty returns a string. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties#getProperty and parseInt takes a string http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp ... I use parseInt in many places, and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are using a value from the spreadsheet with var value = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D13").getValue().toString(); 
This is were you are getting the decimal as Google spreadsheets will default to one decimal place. You will need to highlight the column or cell and change the format to Number>Rounded to get rid of it.
I am sure i am missing some components of your full script here, however have you tried the "getLastRow" function? There are some scripts in the tutorials that use it and it is a tried tested and true method of finding the last row of the sheet.